# Get username in magnolia

Tags: magnolia

I am using the following command to get the username in a custom magnolia class:`String userName = MgnlContext.getInstance().getJCRSession("website").getUserID();`
Instead of getting the name of the user who is signed on in magnolia when the command was triggered I am getting **admin** for the value. How can I get the real user name - the one who signed on to magnolia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually to get current user, what you want is to either inject `MgnlContext` or get it via `MgnlContext.getInstance()` call.
Once you have context, you call `ctx.getUser().getName()` to get current user name.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject `info.magnolia.cms.security.SecuritySupport` to your class and use

`info.magnolia.cms.security.SecuritySupport#getUserManager()`
afterwards, you are exposed to plenty of utility method that one can fetch all users or users by group etc.

Comment: Thank you @ducaz035. I could also probably fetch the JCR components's _mgnl:lastModifiedBy_ property since to be more precise I need the last user who changed the page, component or area.